# android for loop with string [] array

Tags: android, for-loop

I can make individual `strings` from a `string [] array` like this for example :

```
//first, make stringArray1 the same size as arrayList1
stringArray1 = new String[arrayList1.size()];

//stringArray1 will contain all the values in arrayList1
stringArray1 = arraylist1.toArray(stringArray1);

//for each value in stringArray1 make it into an individual string,
//called string1
            for(String string1: stringArray1 )

            {
                System.out.println("string1 is " + string1);

             }
```

Can you tell me how I would put another string conversion from `string [] array` into the same `for` loop? Both `arrayList1` and `arrayList2` are exact same size. I thought I would be able to use `&&` but no joy. I'm getting `'Expression expected'`. Or do I need to have two different `for` loops?
This is what I have:

```
//first, make stringArray1 the same size as arrayList1
stringArray1 = new String[arrayList1.size()];

//second, make stringArray2 the same size as arrayList2
stringArray2 = new String[arrayList2.size()];

//stringArray1 will contain all the values in arrayList1
stringArray1 = arraylist1.toArray(stringArray1);

//stringArray2 will contain all the values in arrayList2
stringArray2 = arraylist2.toArray(stringArray2);

//for each value in stringArray1 make it into an individual string,
//called string1. Do likewise for string2
            for(String string1: stringArray1 && String string2: stringArray2)

            {
                System.out.println("string1 is " + string1);
                System.out.println("string2 is " + string2);

             }
```

Comment: That will not work. Either two for each loops or collect the arrays into one.

Comment: Also from the point that both arrays can have different sizes. Then the for each loop can't handle that.

Comment: @MuratK.Thanks for comment, both arrays will be the exact same size.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with android . I think you should use java tag rather android tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot iterate over two arrays at the same time using an enhanced for-loop (foreach loop). That is because such a foreach loop internally uses an `Iterator` instance to iterate over the elements.

You have several options:

- Use a simple `for` loop:

  ```java
  for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(arr1[i]);
      System.out.println(arr2[i]);
  }
  ```

  Of course, you have to guarantee that `arr1.length` is not greater than `arr2.length`, otherwise an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is emitted.

  To silently stop if one of the arrays is exhausted, you could just calculate the lowest of the two:

  ````java
  for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(arr1.length, arr2.length); i++) {
      System.out.println(arr1[i]);
      System.out.println(arr2[i]);
  }

  Alternatively, you can use iterators:

  ```java
  Iterator<T> it1 = arr1.iterator();
  Iterator<U> it2 = arr2.iterator();
  while (it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext()) {
      // Do something with it1.next()
      // Do something with it2.next()
  }
  ````
- You can also change the code producing the two arrays, and make sure it uses *a single `List`* with an encapsulating object containing both an element from the first array and the corresponding one from the second array.

Answer (score 2):

If they have the same size you can do something like:

```
for ( i=0; i<arrayList1.size();i++){
   System.out.println("string1 is " + arrayList1[i]);
   System.out.println("strin2 is " + arrayList2[i]);
}
```

But to use `arrayList1.size()` is not the best way I think

Comment: just to be safe you should check if either `arrayList1.size()` or `arrayList2.size()` is greater than the other to avoid exceptions

Comment: Great,will try when home. Maybe a try-catch is best then, in case of exception ?

Comment: either this or you just check `if(arrayList1.size()==arrayList1.size()){ ...}`